# InterruptedException: Is Thread.currentThread().interrupt() necessary as the interrupted flag is set

Tags: java, exception, interrupted-exception

We all know that when catching an interruptedexception we are supposed to
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

However, from my tests, that flag is already set.

```
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
           try {
              Thread.sleep(1000L);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
           }
        });
        t.start();
        System.out.println(t.isInterrupted());
        t.interrupt();
        System.out.println(t.isInterrupted());
```

Prints:

```
false
true
```

So what is the point of that commented out line?

Answer (score 2):

If the line is commented out and you try to check in the thread itself if it is interrupted, you will get false as response.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         // Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());//false
 });
```

If you execute the line you get true.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());//true
 });
```

Edit:
The use of `interrupt()` is to inform the thread that it should be terminated. It replaces the `stop()` method which immediately terminates a thread at the currently executed line. Since stopping leaves files or streams open, this way is deprecated. The interrupt should be used to safely close all open streams and then safely terminate the thread. If the thread does not have the ability to create ghosts (leave streams/files open), the handling can be omitted. However, it should always be remembered that the `interrupt()` method does not terminate the thread, instead it continues to execute the code after the exception as if nothing had happened.

Comment: Yeah ... so the only point of interrupting the thread, is if the thread itself wants to know during the catch part. If you don't care, then I think setting the thread interrupt is faily useless. I wrote an uncaughtexceptionhandler and the thread interrupt flag being set was evident only in that. So perhaps for uncaught exception handlers?

Comment: Yes it is just an info for the thread itself. If you don't need the information you can leave it out. It is needed if you want to stop the thread but there are still files or streams open that need to be closed and would be left open by `Thread.stop()`.